# Missed characters in cout_ing?

Tags: c++, binary, ascii, binaryfiles, binary-data

i'm trying to make a code can convert an image to binary(o-1) and it worked well but there are many symbols (ASCII characters) missed in the result of my code while when i open the image in hex editor i find the full image converted and i find these characters converted too , and when i tried to make a counter beside every binary comes out , i noticed the counter stops before the missed character and starts again after passing it.
here is my code..

```
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   ifstream file("E:\\2.jpg");
   string myString;
   ofstream fout("E:\\mnmn.txt");
   while(file>>myString)
   {
   for (size_t i = 0; i < myString.size(); ++i)  
 {
  fout <<i <<"-"<< bitset<8>(myString.c_str()[i])<<endl;
 }}
return 0;
```

}

the result comes out like:

```
0-11111111
1-11011000
2-11111111
3-11100000
4-00000000
5-00010000
0-01001010    \\passed 00001001 character and started the counter from the beginig
1-00000000
etc...
```

Thank you in advance for anyone would help.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the istream with `ios::binary`:

```
ifstream file("E:\\2.jpg", ios::binary);
```

If this is not present data will be interpreted as text and some bytes which may represent control characters may be discarded.

Additionally try using istream::read() to read the binary file. This member function doesn't try to interpret control characters.
This could look something like this (untested):

```
file.seekg(std::ios_base::end);
size_t length = file.tellg();
file.seekg(std::ios_base::beg);
myString.reserve(length);
file.read(&myString[0], length);
```

Comment: yeah exactly character like 00001001 discarded ... is there anything i can do !!

Comment: I added an example for that. Maybe it helps

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read `std::string` from a binary file (and not opening the file as `ios::binary`). [Binary file = "not text"]

You should really use `stream::read` to read data from a binary file. The `std::string` and `operator >>` aren't really meant to read raw binary data, and will certainly not work well for this purpose.

The reason it stops reading and skips over the byte `00001001` is that it is a "whitespace character" - tab in this particular case. You can stop it skipping whitespace by `file >> noskipws >> something;`, but it doesn't help the fact that it will, always, stop reading at newline. Since you can't guarantee that a jpg file doesn't contain a byte for newline, it's impossible to process JPG files using `operator>>` for strings.

Comment: Would you please tell me how can i do that ??? .. how can i convert jpg or video to zero and one without skips ?

Comment: If you don't care much about efficiency (and you are writing to console output, so that's going to dwarf any other thing), you could just loop around `while(file.get(c)) ...` where `c` is a `char` - most of your existing code would remain, except you are reading a byte at a time. I hope you have a fairly small JPG, because large file would make a very long output...